# Basic c++ question: what happens if I create something in a function and return it?

Tags: c++

What happens if I create something in a function and return it? In particular, is the object itself returned, or a copy of it?

Or, if not, what happens in these specific cases:

1. The object I create is an actual object.
2. I create a raw pointer to an object.
3. A shared pointer.
4. A unique pointer.

If you want to see some code, here's one with a raw-pointer.

```
myObject* func()
{
    ptr = new Object();
    return ptr;
}

myObject* somePtr = func(); //what happens here?
```

Comment: Your description is unclear.    On point 1, in what circumstances would you consider that an object you create is *not* an "actual object"?

Comment: Anything that is not a pointer is an object, is what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

> In particular, is the object itself returned, or a copy of it?

1. If you return an actual object, then a copy of the actual object is made.
2. If you return a raw pointer, then a copy of the raw pointer is made. Just to clarify: Pointers are objects too.
3. If you return a shared pointer, then a copy of the shared pointer is made. I hope you're beginning to see a pattern here.
4. A unique pointer cannot be copied, but see the next paragraph.

Note that there is a difference in what kind of an expression is returned. In the example program, you return an lvalue. Lvalues are copied. If you returned an rvalue instead, then the returned object would be moved rather than copied.

For trivial objects like raw pointer, there is no difference between moving and copying. For a unique pointer, the distinction is very important, since they can only be moved; not copied.

Since C++17, prvalues are not even moved, but rather constructed directly in place of the object that the return value initializes. This behaviour can also occur in place of a copy/move prior to C++17, and also for lvalues to local variables, but that behaviour is an optimization and not guaranteed to occur.

No copies of the dynamic `Object` instance are made in your example program.

Answer (score 0):

example provided by you is case 2 : As you are returning the pointer then a new variable somePtr will assign with the pointer value you return which point to the same object as ptr was pointing.

Case 3 & 4 : Depends on the smart pointer you use and return, references will be updated so as the ownership also in some cases.

Case 1 : as understood you are telling to return object itself then object copy will be performed.

Comment: For case 1, as @user2079303 points out, when an object is returned by value it is (almost always) constructed in place at the calling site so that no copy is necessary.  There are ways to code the called function that prevent this from happening but that is unusual.

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes, either copy constructor or assignment operator will get called but finally there will be a new object with the same state as ptr is pointing.

Comment: That's not so.  In almost all cases, when an object is returned by value, that does not happen, see my answer below.

Comment: @PaulSanders Added my comments in your post , please modify your code and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify case 1 (return object by value), the following code does *not* copy the returned object:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class  C
{
public:
    C (const std::string& s) { m_s = s; std::cout << "Construct " << s << "\n"; }
    C (const C& c) { std::cout << "Copy " << c.m_s << " to " << m_s << "\n"; }
    C (const C&& c) { std::cout << "Move " << c.m_s << " to " << m_s << "\n"; }
    C& operator= (C c)  { std::cout << "Copy assign " << c.m_s << " to " << m_s << "\n"; return *this; }
    C& operator= (C&& c)  { std::cout << "Move assign " << c.m_s << " to " << m_s << "\n"; return *this; }
    ~C () { std::cout << "Destroy " << m_s << "\n"; }
private:
    std::string m_s;
};

C make_C ()
{
    return C ("42");
}

int main()
{
    C c = make_C ();
}
```

Output:

```
Construct 42
Destroy 42
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GM9A1pV5LYioZLAh)

Comment: This is happening because you are creating an object on a stack within make_C() function and returning it. Create an object globally or create it in the heap and return it from the function make_C() then copy constructor will get called.

Comment: @Sanjeev Sure, but that wasn't the question I was attempting to address.